# ¿Se puede convertir una variable en un delegado mediante casting o algo similar? C#

Tags: c#, punteros, diccionarios, casting, delegados

He creado un diccionario tal y como se ve en el código abajo. Ha sido la única forma que he encontrado de lograr que el valor de la variable "myCondition" se actualice dentro del campo Tvalue del diccionario.

```
public class MyClass
{       
    delegate bool Delegate();
    Dictionary<string, Delegate> map;
    bool myCondition;

    public MyClass()
    {
        map = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
        map.Add("key", MyDelegate); 
    }       

    public bool MyDelegate()
    {
        return myCondition;
    }
 }
```

Me gustaría poder prescindir de la función `MyDelegate()` y colocar la variable "*myCondition*" directamente en el diccionario... Básicamente lo que quiero es pasarle un puntero a esa variable, pero por lo que he podido observar en C# los punteros están casi que "prohibidos".

He pensado que a lo mejor se puede hacer algún tipo de casting y convertir esa variable en función y así hacerla pasar por un delegado... algo como en el código siguiente:

```
public class MyClass
{        
    delegate bool Delegate();
    Dictionary<string, Delegate> map;
 
    public MyClass()
    {
        map = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();    
        bool myCondition;
        
        public MyClass()
        {
             map.Add("key", (Delegate)myCondition);
             map.Add("key", (Func)myCondition);
        }   

    }
```

¿Existe alguna forma de poder hacer algo así? ¿Cómo se haría?

Gracias!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No entiendo muy bien a que te refieres con *convertir la variable a función*, algo que no creo que sea posible. Lo que si puedes es omitir la variable y definir una funcion (`Func`) que calcule el valor a devolver.

Te pongo un ejemplo. Primero definimos el diccionario, con el `TValue` a `Func<bool>`:

```
private Dictionary<string, Func<bool>> map = new Dictionary<string, Func<bool>>();
```

Posteriormente, simplemente añadimos una entrada de diccionario definiendo que debemos devolver, en este caso `myCondition`:

```
map.Add("key", new Func<bool>( ()=> { return myCondition; }));
```

Por último, podemos consultarlo llamando a la función devuelta por el diccionario:

```
if (map["key"]())
{
    Console.WriteLine("si");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("no");
}
```

Como dato adicional, podrías perfectamente calcular el valor definiendo `Func` para que pueda aceptar valores de entrada:

```
private Dictionary<string, Func<int,bool>> map = new Dictionary<string, Func<int,bool>>();

//añadimos una funcion que devuelve el modulo del entero que se le pase
map.Add("par", new Func<int,bool>( x => { return x % 2==0; })); 

if (map["par"](3))
{
    Console.WriteLine("par");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("impar");
}
```

Comment: Gracias Pikoh!! Muy buena explicación!!... En cuanto a lo de convertir una variable en función no sé si en C# será posible... pero por ejemplo en Haskel si es posible (es programación funcional, todo son funciones incluso las variables)... De todas formas con tu explicación creo que estoy servido!! Muchas Gracias y Saludos!!